# sequence id increment with date - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create an increment number licence with the current date of the year + an increment number but i really don't know how to do this i know MYSQl does not support sequences but i would like to know if there is a way to solve the problem

here my controller

```
public function create(){
$licence = new Licence ;
$licence ->num_licence = Carbon::now()->year -- i would like here to put the current year like 2017 with a random unique number to get the format like 20170001 for exemple !

...
```

how to acheice this? thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does the number need to be reset every year?

Comment: yes :) it needs to be reset every year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.uniqid.php) function with current year as prefix.

```
public function create(){
   $licence = new Licence ;
   $num_liscence_exist=true;
   while($num_liscence_exist){
      $num_liscence=uniqid(Carbon::now()->year);
      if (!Liscence_Table::where('num_liscence', '=',"'".$num_liscence."'")->exists()) {
         $liscence->num_liscence=$num_liscence;
         $num_liscence_exist=false;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help ! in my num_licence field in the database i set the type value as an unique id or a string type ?

Comment: you have to add a while loop and check if the generated key already exists in your table....if you use uniqid the num_liscence has to have varchar type --see update

Comment: thanks for your reply , so with this i will never have same numbers conflicts right ?

Comment: yes you will only assign the number if it is not existing in your table, else you have to generate a new one.

Comment: do you how how how to generate the key with specific number of caracters something like 2017L45685 ?

Comment: you can use substr function like this :`substr(strtoupper(uniqid("2017")),0,10)` It is not recommended to use substr here but since you check if this key exists before saving it then you can use it.

Comment: perfect ! yes if i made the method with verification there will be no conflicts with this method substr ! thanks a lot i will check right now . just one more question do you know how to display only "17" instead of "2017" using carbon ? many thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

Generate the random id using `uniqid()` and concatenate with date:

```
public function create(){
    $liscence=new Liscence();
    $year = Carbon::now()->year;
    $liscence->num_liscence= $year. uniqid();
    $liscence->save();
}
```

Comment: awesome i will test right now !!! thanks for the help !!! in my database for the colomun " num_licence " i put it as a unique id or string type ?

Comment: `uniqid()` will generate a sequence, but it's worth noting that it'll have gaps. That can be fine or not depending on actual needs. (Many of my customers are really annoyed by gaps, there must be some psychological explanation.)

Comment: this number will be search by customers so i will index it ! by the way i checked and i got this random number : 2017589adc05eeb9b could i custom it as maybe something like 2017 with prefix L and 4 numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

using uniqid() get unique number or also you can use time stamp with it:

```
$liscence=new Liscence();
$year = Carbon::now()->year;
$liscence->num_liscence= $year. strtoupper(uniqid()) . Carbon::now()->timestamp;
$liscence->save();
```

Will look like : 2017ABC011486543961

Comment: that's really cool ! so my number will be really unique , any conflicts or double values will happen right ?

Comment: perfect ! could i custom the number of characters ? to get somethings like 2017L with 5 numbers

Comment: Than might be chance to conflict. Suppose 2017A or again 2017A. I Thinks this format is better if you like !

Comment: `Carbon::now()->timestamp` is not always unique. two or more records can be inserted at same time.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence needs to be stored somewhere so I doubt there's a sensible pure-PHP solution. But since you're already using MySQL there's no reason to not use it. I'd create a database table for that, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE licence_sequence (
    sequence_year YEAR NOT NULL,
    next_value INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (sequence_year, next_value)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

*(Ugly `sequence_year` name was chosen to avoid having to quote it every time.)*

You then have to manage this from code, including:

- Ensuring you have rows for every year as you need them (this can be as simple as populating data for all years for next century).
- Ensuring you don't assign the same value to different items.

A rough overview of stuff to consider:

- You can (and should) make your licence number a unique index to avoid dupes.
- You can use transactions to avoid unnecessary gaps. Transaction should wrap all the operations involved:

  1. Get next sequence number
  2. Save it into new licence
  3. Increment next number
- You need to ensure atomic operations in a multi-tasking environment. This is the hardest part. I've been lately being playing with [MySQL named locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) and they seem to work correctly.